# How to construct a list of tuples of all possible combinations

Tags: python

I just can't come up with a way to solve my problem: x is an integer. I want a list of all possibles combinations of  x-tuples where those tuples' elements are in range from 0 to x (excluding x).

So if `x = 3` I have 3^3 combinations: `[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(0,1,2),(0,2,0),(0,2,1),(0,2,2),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,0),(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(2,0,0),(2,0,1),(2,0,2),(2,1,0),(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(2,2,0),(2,2,1),(2,2,2)]`.

If `x = 4` I would have 4^4 combinations with 4-tuples where the elements of those tuples are in {0,1,2,3}.

Comment: Those are called *permutations* https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with permutations, thanks anyways :D

Comment: Read the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python). It will solve your problem. The answer is: `import itertools` and then `answer = [i for i in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=3)]`

Comment: ok yea, it does solve my problem. Thank you, I will read into this more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the proper way to use `itertools` to get what you want:

```
list(itertools.product(range(3), repeat=3))
```

The output is:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1),
 (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0),
 (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```

Of course, this can scale up by using values other than 3.  In general:

```
list(itertools.product(range(x), repeat=x))
```

will work for any `x`.

Comment: YES! That's it, thanks so much, you saved my life :D!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a list comprehension:

```
mylist = [(x,y,z) for x in range(3) for y in range(3) for z in range(3)]
```

Note that using itertools.permutations(range(3)) doesn't generate duplicates, just the permutations of the set (0, 1, 2). I.e. you won't get (1, 1, 2), etc.

Comment: Yea that's the solution if I only care about x = 3. But I want a list for any x..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not permatations, but permutations with repeats perhaps.
Anyway, `itertools.product()` is doing that:

```
list(itertools.product([0,1,2],repeats=3))
```

result:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```

oh it's a dupe. But I found it too :-)

(Side remark: *combinations* are about subsets, and thus order of elements does not matter to them)